# How to insert class in the middle of inheritance chain?

Tags: c#, inheritance, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have classes as below, wherein A : B indicates A inherits from B:

GatewayBaseActivity : SDKBaseActivity : AppCompatActivity

and

FormsAppCompatActivity : AppCompatActivity

How do I make it so I have a class with all of the functionality of GatewayBaseActivity, but instead inherits as so:

GatewayBaseActivity : SDKBaseActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity : AppCompatActivity

Essentially sticking the FormsAppCompatActivity between SDKBaseActivity and AppCompatActivity in the the heritage tree.

These classes all come from Xamarin, Android, and Airwatch. What's the best way to do this without rewriting half of the classes?

Comment: It might make more sense if you used the actual inheritance indicator (`:`) and provided psuedo code examples

Comment: You will need to restructure the inheritance that is already there

Comment: Write your own that extends from the "highest" parent. In this case, it would be `GatewayBaseActivity`. If the code is open-source, you could potentially re-write an `Activity` to flatten these structures to be more simple from a `FormsAppCompatActivity` for example. This much inheritence has code smell to it.

Comment: You write your `FormsAppCompatActivity` and change `AppCompatActivity`, there is no rewriting half your class hierarchy, you only have to modify the class that inhertis from the new one you are inserting in the heirarchy. If you dont own the code of `AppCompatActivity` then you can't really insert anything before it because you don't have the right to.

Comment: So I would have a class say GatewayBaseActivityForms : GatewayBaseActivity : SDKBaseActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity : AppCompatActivity

Comment: Im Not Sure If I understand your question but you cant Change the hierarchy of already defined classes from Others librariries. But What you can do is : instead ofis-a Relation you can have has-a Relation. Which means your class would inherit from GatewayBaseActivity und have a variable of Type FormsAppCompatActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following hierarchy:

```
class A { }
class B: A { }
class D: B { }
class E: D { }
```

Inserting a class `C` in the obivious spot is pretty trivial; you just need to modify `D`.

```
class C: B { }
class D: C { }
```

If you don't own `D` and can't acces and alter its implementation then there is nothing you can do; you can't change the base class of a third party implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You suggest to implement classic multi-inheritance. In C# (and many others languages) that paradigm should be replaced by declaring and implementing multiple interfaces. So,

- you can define some common (for all classes you mentioned) abstract interface and implement it in classes you want.
- or you can define interface for FormsAppCompatActivity and implement it in inheritance chain GatewayBaseActivity -> SDKBaseActivity

But the work complexity and time amount it can take, especially in comparison with, as you said, "rewriting half of the classes" strongly depends on your design purposes. I would say, the necessity to inject alien class inside inheritance chain points to bad design. So, I recommend to think about design, and use interfaces, if you do need to combine the functionality of these classes.

Comment: For promoting composition over inheritance